# Backpropagation neural network, too many neurons in layer causing output to be too high

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent, feed-forward

Having neural network with alot of inputs causes my network problems like

> Neural network gets stuck and feed forward calculation always gives output as 
>   1.0 because of the output sum being too big and while doing backpropagation, sum of gradients will be too high what causes the
>   learning speed to be too dramatic.

Neural network is using tanh as an active function in all layers.
Giving alot of thought, I came up with following solutions:

1. Initalizing smaller random weight values ( WeightRandom / PreviousLayerNeuronCount )

or

2. After calculation the sum of either outputs or gradients, dividing the sum with the number of 'neurons in previus layer for output sum' and number of 'neurons in next layer for gradient sum' and then passing sum into activation/derivative function.

I don't feel comfortable with solutions I came up with.

Solution 1. does not solve problem entirely. Possibility of gradient or output sum getting to high is still there. Solution 2. seems to solve the problem but I fear that it completely changes network behavior in a way that it might not solve some problems anymore.

What would you suggest me in this situation, keeping in mind that reducing neuron count in layers is not an option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/jj658979.aspx, you shouldn't have that problem

Answer (score 0):

General things that affect the output backpropagation include weights and biases of early elections, the number of hidden units, the amount of exercise patterns, and long iterations. As an alternative way, the selection of initial weights and biases there are several algorithms that can be used, one of which is an algorithm `Nguyen widrow`. You can use it to initialize the weights and biases early, I've tried it and gives good results.